# Making the gwt toolbar nicer

Tags: css, gwt, toolbar

I am working on a project that already has begun being developed. ON some page, there is some textarea and a text-editor using  gwt, from which I know nothing. The fact is that the style of the toolbar is very austere. Does anybody knows some way to make this toolbatr nicer, is there any doc somewhere ?

Best,
Newben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a comprehensive [guide on styling GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's precisely what I was looking for !